# Exception in port type using Suds

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds, aramex

I am trying to connect to Aramex shipping SOAP API using Python Suds using following code:

```
import suds
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('file:///home/test/test_wsdl_aramex/shipments-tracking-api-wsdl.wsdl',cache=None)
```

But after starting, I get the following exception:

```
>     raise Exception("portType '%s', not-found" % self.type)
Exception: portType 'i0:Service_dd1_0', not-found
```

The WSDL file source can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/HW5zNNPA).

Comment: There are errors in WDSL file:                                    WSDL Validation Errors Found. We were unable to successfully validate the WSDL file at shipments-tracking-api-wsdl 
We encountered the following errors:

Service "Service_1_0" : Port "BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" points to undefined binding
Binding "BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" references undefined PortType

Comment: @adamr thank you for pointing out the issue, now comes the question, whether we can skip the validation part in SUDS !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here:

```
<wsdl:binding type="i0:Service_1_0" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
```

And

> The binding element has two attributes - name and type.
>
> The name attribute (you can use any name you want) defines the name of
>   the binding, and the type attribute points to the port for the
>   binding, in this case the "glossaryTerms" port.

So parser can't find port `type="i0:Service_1_0"`, in this wsdl file there are two ports definition:

```
<wsdl:portType name="Service_1_0">
    <wsdl:operation name="TrackShipments">
      <wsdl:input name="ShipmentTrackingRequest" message="tns:ShipmentTrackingRequest" wsaw:Action="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipments"/>
      <wsdl:output name="ShipmentTrackingResponse" message="tns:ShipmentTrackingResponse" wsaw:Action="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipmentsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:service name="Service_1_0">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
      <soap:address location="http://ws.aramex.net/shippingapi/tracking/service_1_0.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

So now you know what is wrong(change type in wsdl:binding), and you can't pass the validation of that.

Comment: what should be the new binding type ? I tried with binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" and things seems to be working but not sure what will be the "magical" effect.

Comment: When your portType name is "Service_1_0" in <wsdl:binding/> type should be "tns:Service_1_0", and as you done binding in <wsdl:port> should be tns instead of i0. Your wsdl file was uncompatible with w3schools wsdl standard http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's the issue from Aramex (the shipping company, http://www.aramex.com/), so possibly some words from them will explain it or they'll have to fix it. Thanks a lot for your efforts.