# Error in generating java classes from wsdl

Tags: java, service, web, wsdl, webservices-client

Recently i started work on implementing web service client from eclipse. i got wsdl from aramex.com/developers. I wanted to implement a shipment tracking client. but when i generating java classes from below wsdl file it gives me below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Emitter failure.  There is an undefined binding (BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0) in the WSDL document.
Hint: make sure <port binding=".."> is fully qualified.
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.checkForUndefined(SymbolTable.java:570)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:715)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

below is the wsdl file i got from aramex.com/developers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
 xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
 xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
 xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
 xmlns:i0="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1" 
 xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
 xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
 xmlns:tns="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" 
 xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
 targetNamespace="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" name="Service_1_0">
  <wsdl:binding type="i0:Service_1_0" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="TrackShipments">
      <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipments"/>
      <wsdl:input name="ShipmentTrackingRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="ShipmentTrackingResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xsd:element name="ShipmentTrackingRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element type="tns:ClientInfo" name="ClientInfo" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element type="tns:Transaction" name="Transaction" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element type="q1:ArrayOfstring" name="Shipments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:boolean" name="GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:complexType name="ClientInfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UserName" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Password" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Version" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="AccountNumber" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="AccountPin" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="AccountEntity" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="AccountCountryCode" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:ClientInfo" name="ClientInfo" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="Transaction">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Reference1" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Reference2" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Reference3" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Reference4" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Reference5" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:Transaction" name="Transaction" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:element name="ShipmentTrackingResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element type="tns:Transaction" name="Transaction" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element type="tns:ArrayOfNotification" name="Notifications" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:boolean" name="HasErrors" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element type="q2:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY" name="TrackingResults" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfNotification">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="tns:Notification" name="Notification" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:ArrayOfNotification" name="ArrayOfNotification" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="Notification">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Code" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Message" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:Notification" name="Notification" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfTrackingResult">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="tns:TrackingResult" name="TrackingResult" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:ArrayOfTrackingResult" name="ArrayOfTrackingResult" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="TrackingResult">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="WaybillNumber" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UpdateCode" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UpdateDescription" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:dateTime" name="UpdateDateTime"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UpdateLocation" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Comments" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="ProblemCode" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:TrackingResult" name="TrackingResult" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfstring">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:ArrayOfstring" name="ArrayOfstring" nillable="true"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo>
            <IsDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</IsDictionary>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Key" nillable="true"/>
                <xsd:element type="q3:ArrayOfTrackingResult" name="Value" nillable="true" xmlns:q3="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element type="tns:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY" name="ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
      <xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="anyType" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="anyURI" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:base64Binary" name="base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="boolean" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="byte" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="dateTime" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="decimal" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:double" name="double" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:float" name="float" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:int" name="int" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:long" name="long" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:QName" name="QName" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:short" name="short" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="string" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:unsignedByte" name="unsignedByte" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:unsignedInt" name="unsignedInt" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:unsignedLong" name="unsignedLong" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:unsignedShort" name="unsignedShort" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element type="tns:char" name="char" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="char">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element type="tns:duration" name="duration" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="duration">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
          <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
          <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element type="tns:guid" name="guid" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="guid">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:QName" name="FactoryType"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:ID" name="Id"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:IDREF" name="Ref"/>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ShipmentTrackingRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ShipmentTrackingRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ShipmentTrackingResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ShipmentTrackingResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="Service_1_0">
    <wsdl:operation name="TrackShipments">
      <wsdl:input name="ShipmentTrackingRequest" message="tns:ShipmentTrackingRequest" wsaw:Action="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipments"/>
      <wsdl:output name="ShipmentTrackingResponse" message="tns:ShipmentTrackingResponse" wsaw:Action="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipmentsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:service name="Service_1_0">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
      <soap:address location="http://ws.aramex.net/shippingapi/tracking/service_1_0.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

i did not change any part of the wsdl file.can someone point me the error in above wsdl?

update: anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1):

The wsdl is not correct [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999476/exception-in-port-type-using-suds)

please make the following modifications

1. change 
   binding="i0:B to  binding="tns:B
2. move the binding block from start to just before service wsdl

or use the below patch

```
    index b7f8847..3eaa658 100644
    --- a/aramex_tracking.wsdl
    +++ b/aramex_tracking.wsdl
    @@ -1,17 +1,5 @@
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:i0="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" name="Service_1_0">
    -  <wsdl:binding type="i0:Service_1_0" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
    -    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    -    <wsdl:operation name="TrackShipments">
    -      <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipments"/>
    -      <wsdl:input name="ShipmentTrackingRequest">
    -        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    -      </wsdl:input>
    -      <wsdl:output name="ShipmentTrackingResponse">
    -        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    -      </wsdl:output>
    -    </wsdl:operation>
    -  </wsdl:binding>
       <wsdl:types>
         <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
           <xsd:element name="ShipmentTrackingRequest">
    @@ -168,9 +156,21 @@
           <wsdl:output name="ShipmentTrackingResponse" message="tns:ShipmentTrackingResponse" wsaw:Action="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipmentsResponse"/>
         </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:portType>
    +  <wsdl:binding type="tns:Service_1_0" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
    +    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    +    <wsdl:operation name="TrackShipments">
    +      <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/Service_1_0/TrackShipments"/>
    +      <wsdl:input name="ShipmentTrackingRequest">
    +        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    +      </wsdl:input>
    +      <wsdl:output name="ShipmentTrackingResponse">
    +        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    +      </wsdl:output>
    +    </wsdl:operation>
    +  </wsdl:binding>
       <wsdl:service name="Service_1_0">
    -    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
    +    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0">
           <soap:address location="http://ws.aramex.net/shippingapi/tracking/service_1_0.svc"/>
         </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>
    -</wsdl:definitions>
    \ No newline at end of file
    +</wsdl:definitions>
```