# Error in generating Java from WSDL: java.io.IOException: Emitter failure

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, aramex

I'm trying to integrate the [Aramex Shipments Tracking API](http://www.aramex.com/developers/aramex-apis/42466/Shipments-Tracking-API). I downloaded the WSDL file and went through
web services → web service client → provided service definition for WSDL file → clicked next and finish. But then I get the following error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Emitter failure.  
There is an undefined binding (BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0) in the WSDL document.
Hint: make sure <port binding=".."> is fully qualified.
java.io.IOException: Emitter failure.  There is an undefined binding (BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0) in the WSDL document.
Hint: make sure <port binding=".."> is fully qualified.
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.checkForUndefined(SymbolTable.java:570)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:715)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you please post the WSDLpart creating problem for you.

Comment: Form stacktrace it also seems i am assuming you are missing some path names/URL path, please check that also

Comment: i created the new web project in eclipse and i put wsdl file inside src folder.so which path  are you assuming to miss?

Comment: i also tried from commnad prompt but geeting error !! sandip@sandip-G41MT-S2:~/Downloads$ wsimport shipments-tracking-api-wsdl.wsdl
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] wsdl:binding "{http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1}BasicHttpBinding_Service_1_0" not found in the wsdl: file:/home/sandip/Downloads/shipments-tracking-api-wsdl.wsdl

Comment: I am not sure if you have proper http binding/soap binding . Can you please share your WSDL snapshot.

Comment: i have downloaded it from above url http://www.aramex.com/content/uploads/109/232/42254/shipments-tracking-api-wsdl.zip and didnt change anything in that.i also want to request and response mechanism by using soap

Comment: This seems to solve a very similar problem, probably caused by the same error in the WSDL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999476/exception-in-port-type-using-suds